# Converting a for loop from Windows to Bash

Tags: bash, wsh

I've been stuck on a particular for loop in a Windows script and I can't find any help on how to translate it to its Bash equivalent. The code is here:

```
for f "tokens=2 delims=#" %%a in $step; do set devnum=%%a
set $devnum=$devnum:)=%
```

I understand that it's looping through the variable `$step` I just don't know how to do the tokens and delimiters in Bash. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In DOS the for loop syntax is `FOR %A IN (list) DO command [ parameters ]` (`%%A` is used in a batch-file compared to `%A` used on the command line). In bash the syntax is `for var in list; do command; done` In your case you have:

```
for f "tokens=2 delims=#" %%a in $step; do set devnum=%%a set $devnum=$devnum:)=%
```

The loop provides some function or executable `f` using `"tokens=2 delims=#"` for the variable `%%a` where `%%a` will take on the values in `$step` each time the loop executes setting `devnum=%%a` (the present value from `$step` and setting `$devnum=$devnum:)=` (whatever the modification to the initial devnum value).

The translation to a bash `for` loop will not only require the translation of the `for` loop syntax, but will also require translation of the `$step` list and the translation of the `commands`. The `for` loop (without list and command translation) becomes:

```
for $a in (whatever list $step is); do
    tmpvar=$(f "tokens=2 delims=#" $a)  # the translated f will be done inside the loop
    devnum=$tmpvar
    (whatever $devnum=$devnum:)=% translates to)
done
```

Nobody can tell you what `$step` translates to until you show what `$step` is. The same goes for the translation of `f`. That being said, the generic translation of the loop structure will be as shown above unless `f` is something other than a function or executable. I hope that helps. Drop an additional comment or edit your question to provide more information and I'm glad to help further.

**Edit** per comment regarding /f filenameset

That makes more sense. In that case you will use an embedded `while read ln; do ..stuff.. done` loop to process the files and break each line into tokens:

```
for $a in (whatever list $step is); do
    while IFS= read line || [ -n "$line" ] ; do
        (parse $line as needed to get 2 tokens)
        devnum=(some $tmpvar from the token parsing) # these two line may move outside the
        (whatever $devnum=$devnum:)=% translates to) # while loop, depending on the tokens
    done <"$a"
done
```

Since with further information it appears `$step` holds filenames to be read line-by-line and processed into 2 tokens separated with `#` `%%a` will become `$a` holding a filename from `$step` which will be fed into the `while read` loop at the closing `done <"$a"`. `IFS=` unset IFS (but you may use it to break on `#` as well, but I can't tell without seeing your input) the statement `read line || [ -n "$line" ]` will read each line in the filename provided by `$a` and pass `$line` to the inside of the `while` loop to be processed as required into tokens. You will most likely use **parameter expansion/substring extraction** to get the tokens you need from `$line`. Once you have your tokens, you can assign `devnum` as required.

If you will provide the file contents and example of the tokens you need, I'm happy to show you how to extract the tokens with `substring extraction` (and revisit the `IFS` setting, if needed).

**Note:** if `$step` is a list of files as it appears to be, then there is **no** need for a `for` loop at all. All processing can be done with the `while` loop in bash. It is difficult to know exactly what you are attempting to do without you providing examples of what is included in `$step` along with the contents of the files that will be parsed into the tokens.

Comment: OK, I have a typo. It should read:                                                      

`for /f "tokens=2 delims=#" %%a in $step; do set devnum=%%a`  

so that it loops through the list contained in $step using the token and the delimiter and assigning them to %%a. Thats what I haven't been able to figure out in bash. How to do the loop with the params above.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your edit regarding ` /f filenameset`. Take a look. If you provide the additional file/token information, I'm happy to show you how to translate the token extraction as well.